# Lightning Theme Customization?

Tags: lightning, home-page-component, ui

New look and feel of lightning is blue in color, As a part of branding we want to change the color is it possible.
Also I dont see option to set Organization Logo, Currently it shows Salesforce logo. is it not customizable.

Answer (score 1):

Though you probably already figured this out, the Organization Logo issue was likely due to the App Type being "Classic" instead of "Lightning". If you upgrade the old App (a copy of the Classic App is created), then you should be able to update your logo.